# Выборка из нескольких таблиц DBF JDBC

Tags: dbf, java, jdbc, odbc, sql

Имеется база данных Visual Fox Pro, структура папок в ней примерно следующая:

```
Root
|--FOLDER1
|----file1.dbf
|----file2.dbf
|----FOLEDR2
|------file3.dbf
|--FOLDER3
|----file4.dbf
```

работаю с базой через мост odbc-jdbc, создаю подключение например к папке FOLDER1:

```
String url = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Visual FoxPro Driver};SourceType=DBF;SourceDB=Root\FOLDER1; Exclusive=No;Collate=Machine;NULL=NO;DELETED=NO;BACKGROUNDFETCH=NO;"; 
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
```

Но мне нужно сделать выборку из нескольких таблиц в разных папках например:

```
SELECT *
  from file1
  left join file3 on file3.id=file1.id
  left join file4 on file4.id=file1.id
```

Как это реализовать на java и jdbc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JDBC глубоко безразлично какой драйвер, какая БД используется. Как только есть коннект в БД то можно делать любые запросы используя одинаковые для всех БД правила. В самом дубовом варианте работает код:

```
Connection con;
String query; // SQL запрос в виде строки
//...skipped
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
```

Ну а как вытаскивать из `ResultSet` результаты запроса поди сообразите/погуглите? В голове подозреваю не опилки чай?

**Update**

Если речь идет о том, что у вас есть несколько JDBC коннектов к разным таблицам, то как в этом случае построить запрос с несколькими коннектами? В этом случае смотрите в сторону [UnityJDBC](http://www.unityjdbc.com/), который добавляет еще 1 уровень абстрагирования, так что позволяет общаться с несколькими БД коннектами как будто это один JDBC коннект.

Comment: Подозреваю, у @nostradamusъ вопрос по части фокспрошного SQL-синтаксиса: как обратиться к таблице в субдиректории.

Comment: @Barmaley ♦ с запросами к бае проблем у меня нет. У меня вопрос по настройке подключения к БД, нужно обращаться к нескольким таблицам, находящимся в разных директориях

Comment: @nostradamusъ надо яснее выражаться - смотрите апдейт

Comment: @Barmaley ♦ спасибо! именно то, что нужно.